# Can I connect my EU 230V 2.8kW appliance to a US 240V 20A receptacle?

Tags: appliances, 240v

The appliance is a pizza oven with Schuko plug [Picture 1], running at 240V 50-60Hz 2.8Kw. The receptacle is a US 240V 20A [Picture 2] to which is currently connected the PTAC [Picture 3]. Sharing the picture of the circuit panel [Picture 4] and the back of the appliance [Picture 5]

I’ll use the pizza oven once a week and I can not replace receptacle because I live in an apartment. Would this appliance work if plugged in the receptacle shown?

If yes, is it better to replace the cord or use an adapter? I couldn’t find any to buy online.

If not, what other options do I have?

Thank you!

[image: Appliance plug]

[image: Receptacle]

[image: PTAC plug]

[image]

[image]![

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*blink blink* I can't believe it.

We get *so many* variations of "I got this European thing" or "can I plug (huge thing) into (tiny outlet)" or "renting as complication" - and the answer is *always* a huge Nope.  *Until now*.

## Yes, you can!

That receptacle is *exactly* what you need for that appliance.

In fact, if you had the ability to run a new circuit to that appliance, this is exactly what we'd tell you to install.

*You might want to buy a lottery ticket :)*  Luck is with you today. (or skill?)

### Change the plug.

It just takes a common NEMA 6-20 plug that has a strain relief appropriate for that diameter of cable.  Any electrical supply house will have it, and a hardware store or box store might even.

The only way I'd consider an adapter cable is if you made it *yourself* with a TUV-rated Schuko inline *socket*, some 12/3 *cordage*, and the NEMA 6-20P of course.

Even if you could find an adapter, 99% chance it would be some cheap Chinese rubbish that would catch on fire and kill you with toxic smoke while you sleep.  I suppose, if you could find a **high-current** (at least 2.5mm wires) Schuko "power strip" from a reliable vendor of unquestionable quality (Tripp-Lite, Siemens etc.), then I'd say buy it and change the plug to NEMA 6-20P.

Comment: I think you mean 'change the plug', not 'change the socket'.

Comment: It might be as easy as prying the black cover off the pizza oven, unscrewing the terminals at the end of the wires on the schulko plug , and replacing them one for one with the wires from the gray plastic plug.

Comment: @gbronner-- I'd get a new cord for the pizza oven because they probably want to be able to plug the PTAC back in at some point :)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed feedback! I’ll change the plug as you’ve suggested (not the socket, but I think you meant plug). One follow up question, once I change the plug, would it be ok to use an extension cord as well? This one for instance https://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-9-ft-20-Amp-250V-Grey-Air-Conditioner-Extension-Cord-HD-188-327/207072958

Comment: Are we sure this is truly 240?   I don't see a supporting breaker for that outlet.   I'd like to see a voltmeter on it to be sure it's really 240.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Wouldn't it be either the 10/12 or 13/15 breakers? They're both labeled "Heat Pump", and that is a plausible description for a PTAC.

Comment: @DougDeden  Ahh...good point. Could be an outlet for a PTAC. When I saw heat pump I was thinking a mini-split or an outdoor condenser unit hardwired.  Thanks for the comment, it's a great one. upvote from me!

Comment: @TemporaryData -- keep a close eye on the cord to make sure it doesn't overheat, and you'll want to be careful with routing it to avoid winding up with a boxload of pizza oven pieces instead of a pizza oven...

Comment: @TemporaryData, since you're changing the plug anyway, you might as well just change the whole cord out for a longer one that has the plug you need, and that way you don't have to mess about with an extension cord.  You can get them cheap since they're commonly used as server power cords, and you can just clip off the end you don't need.  Here's one example: https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=40086

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback! I’ll go to Home Depot today and buy the plug. Is it the right understanding that the green/yellow wire from the Schuko goes to the ground terminal of the 6-20, the blue neutral wire goes to one of the two sides terminals and the brown hot wire to the other side terminal?

Comment: @TemporaryData yup.  If HD doesn’t have it, try a proper electrical supply house.  It is Very Important for the strain relief to engage sheath of the cord, and be a good fit.  A supply house will have better variety.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine, and replace the cord. Adapters can fail and start fires.

Comment: Short & sweet. Too short & sweet... You got flagged for _length_ and content. Might want to consider a bit of extra filling. ;)

Comment: They can probably keep the existing cord and simply field-fit a NEMA 6-15P on the end